# React Native - Upload image to Elixir Phoenix Framework

Tags: reactjs, react-native, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am using `Elixir Phoenix` as my backend and create an `api` to upload image. I am using `Waffle` hex package to handle the uploading.

so I have a `api`:

```
localhost:4000/uplaod_avatar/
```

and run this function in controller:

```
  def upload_avatar(conn, params) do
    scope = Repo.get(User, 1)
    case AvatarUploader.store({ params["image"], scope }) do
      {:ok, filename} ->
        IO.puts(filename)
        render(conn, "upload.json", params: %{"status" => :success, "filename" => filename})
      _ ->
        render(conn, "upload.json", params: %{"status" => :error})
    end
  end
```

when I test it with `Postman`, everything works. I test it with `formData` as the image shown below:

[image]

this is the data from `Postman`:

> %{"image" => %Plug.Upload{content_type: "image/png",
> filename: "Screenshot 2021-03-10 at 4.31.53 PM.png", path:
> "/var/folders/y7/9j1md31s75n9kwfbs6q073fw0000gn/T//plug-1618/multipart-1618382732-484457522147916-1"}}

It seems like `Phoenix Framework` understand the content data coming in and use `Plug.Upload` to process.

But when I use `React Native` to test (ios version), this is what I do:

```
const data = new FormData();
      data.append('image',{
        name: this.state.fileName,
        type:this.state.fileType,
        uri:this.state.fileUri
      })
```

using the same `api`, I get the data like this:

> %{"image" => <<255, 216, 255, 224, 0, 16, 74, 70, 73, 70, 0, 1, 1, 0,
> 0, 72, 0, 72, 0, 0, 255, 225, 0, 88, 69, 120, 105, 102, 0, 0, 77, 77,
> 0, 42, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 2, 1, 18, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, ...>>}

of course the `api` is not working for `react native`.

How can I convert my data from `react native` to something like the data from `Postman`?

**Update01**
After some poking around, I found out that the code for `Postman` is:

```
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("image", fileInput.files[0], "Screenshot 2021-03-10 at 4.31.53 PM.png");
```

now, the question is, How can I get `fileInput.files[0]` from `React Native`?

Comment: I have no idea about react, but it might be helpful for you to know that what do you receive suspiciously looks like a raw JPEG, because the binary in the image starts with `FF D8 FF`. But AFAIK, JPEG starts with `FF D8 FF D9` and you have `E0` as the forth byte, so something is weird here. In any case, I think you have to explicitly tell react native to uhm use proper encoding.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Thanks for the insight. Honestly I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Would not `data.append('name', 'Screenshot 2021-03-10 at 4.31.53 PM.png'); data.append('file_attachment', fileInput.files[0]);` work? https://aboutreact.com/file-uploading-in-react-native/

Comment: got back the same result.

Comment: Have you explicitly set `headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; '}` with `POST` request as shown in the link above?

Answer (score 0):

like Aleksei said you will need to set `headers`, and just for a small example it will look something like this

```
selectImage(async (result) => {
  try {
    if (!result) throw new Error('Not selected')
    setAvatarLoading(true)

    const localUri = result.uri
    const filename = localUri.split('/').pop()

    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('token', getToken())
    formData.append('file', {
      uri: localUri,
      name: filename,
      type: 'image/jpeg',
    })

    await fetch(avatarEndpoint, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
      header: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' },
    })

    await onChange()
  } catch (ex) {
    console.log(ex)
    throw ex
  } finally {
    setAvatarLoading(false)
  }
})
```

and later you will handle it over the phoenix controller.